# Intuition about the Gaussian processes

Tags: correlation, gaussian-process

As far as I undestand `Gaussian process` (GP) is generalization of the **Normal Distribution** to infinite dimensional case.

- $1d$ case : $x \sim e^{-(x-\mu)^2 / 2 \sigma^2}$
- $Nd$ case: $\mathbf{x} \sim e^{-(\mathbf{x}-\mu^T) \Sigma^{-1} (\mathbf{x}- \mu)/2}$
- (GP) : $x(t) \sim e^{-\int dt^{'} (x(t) - \mu(t)) \Sigma^{-1}(t,t^{'}) (x(t^{'}) - \mu(t^{'})) /2}$

It is alsl claimed in Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_process, that restriction to the finite set of points is the multivariate Gaussian random variable.

My question is how to imagine visually the GP. I would think about a plot, where there is some function, representing the mean $\mu(t)$, and the shading around this mean represents the probability density.

[image]

And the width of the band at each point would correspond to the standard deviation at each point - $\Sigma(t, t)$. However, I wonder how to distinguish cases with different interpoint correlations $\Sigma(t, t^{'})$. Is there an intuitive way to distinguish the case, when is like $\Sigma(t, t) = \delta_{t t^{'}}$ from the case of long-range correlation between points at $t$ and $t^{'}$.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by “distinguishing” them?

Comment: @Tim to look at the figure and say something about the behaviour of $\Sigma(t_1,t_2)$ for $t_1 \neq t_2$

Comment: Nothing, since this shows only a marginal plot. To show a covariance matrix, you would need to plot something it as a heatmap etc.